# Writing excel file to vb6

Tags: excel, vb6

i have an excel file template and i want save the written value in textboxes to the cells of excel using vb6 language.

can anyone help me?

Comment: The VB6 development environment (editor, compiler, et. al.) has been discontinued and is no longer supported by Microsoft. (The VB6 *runtime* is still supported -- e.g., for existing applications.) Strongly recommend you look at VB.Net (or C#.Net, or something else) instead.

Comment: VBA is native to Excel, is that what you mean? If so, search with in the Excel and VBA tags and you will find a lot of information.

Comment: the link is very helpful in creating new excel file in vb6. but i have an excel file and what i want to do is something like putting the values to the cells to my current xls file. (e.g like Editing)

Comment: i got it! thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Excel's automation features from any language that supports COM (directly or indirectly); [here's an example using VB.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb652466.aspx). There are also [examples using VB6](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/t135815.html) out there still, but see my comment on your question, creating new applications with VB6 is a potential problem as the dev environment (compiler, for instance) is no longer supported (the *runtime* still is, for a little while yet, to support apps that already exist). The dev environment still *works* (under XP, at least) to my (sad) knowledge, but expect it to start having trouble as OS's move on...

Comment: VB6 Dev environment and runtime still works under Windows 7.
But VB6 cannot compile to 64 bit so VB6 compiled COM addins will not work with the 64-bit version of Excel 2010.
VBA Macros and addins on the other hand are fully supported in 64-bit Excel (there is a new 64-bit version of the VBA runtime).